# Railscast 240, method render not available with assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I watched Railscast Episode 240 and tried afterwards to spice up my code with ajax.
In fact i want to add ajax to patients/index #patientenajax

```
<h1>Listing patients</h1>

<div id="patientenajax"><%= render "patienten" %></div>
```

Next i in application.js i added:

```
$(function() {
$("#patientenajax th a").live("click", function(){
    $.getScript(this.href);
    return false;
});

});
```

And in an new created file index.js.erb:

```
$("#patientenajax").html("<%= escape_javascript(render "patienten" ) %>")"
```

Somehow i get the error:

```
undefined method `render' for #<#<Class:0x37ceba0>:0x38b75f8>
(in C:/Sites/what2/app/assets/javascripts/index.js.erb)
```

What did i wrong, or how do i have to change my code! Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of quotes are the culprit here, use the following:

```
$("#patientenajax").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'patienten') %>")
```

Update:

> undefined method `render' for #<#:0x38b75f8> (in
>   C:/Sites/what2/app/assets/javascripts/index.js.erb)

And your `index.js.erb` should be in `app/views/patients/` directory not in `app/assets/javascripts` directory.

Comment: @EmSta, Updated my answer.  I think that's the problem based on the path to `index.js.erb` in the error you've posted.